# Find two elements by partial link text

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver, bots

So there is this website [Supreme Website](https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts) and I need to choose an item that matches both keyword variable and color variable.  I can easily choose the item using the keyword like that

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(keyword.get()).click()
```

So, for example, I can click on Formula Crewneck, but I want to be able to decide the color too. But how do I make sure it grabs also my color.get() and clicks the right item that matches both criteria. Thanks

Here is the full code that I have so far just for reference

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("600x400")
screen.title("Super Bot")
screen.configure(background = "red3")

def web():
    name.get()
    email.get()
    telephone.get()
    address.get()
    zipad.get()
    city.get()
    state.get()
    number.get()
    datem.get()
    datey.get()
    cvv.get()
    category.get()
    size.get()
    keyword.get()
    color.get()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\artjo\Desktop\Python\chrome\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/{}'.format(category.get()))

    while True:
     try:
          driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(keyword.get())
          break
     except (NoSuchElementException):
          wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
          waitBis=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'time-zone-name')))
          driver.refresh()

    wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(keyword.get()).click()


name = StringVar()
email = StringVar()
telephone = StringVar()
address = StringVar()
zipad = StringVar()
city = StringVar()
state = StringVar()
number = StringVar()
datem = StringVar()
datey = StringVar()
cvv = StringVar()
category = StringVar()
size = StringVar()
keyword = StringVar()
color = StringVar()

namelabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "name", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
namelabel.place(x = 30, y = 62)
nameentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = name, width = 20, bg = "white")
nameentry.place(x = 130, y = 64)

emaillabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "e-mail", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
emaillabel.place(x = 30, y = 102)
emailentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = email, width = 20, bg = "white")
emailentry.place(x = 130, y = 104)

tellabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "telephone", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
tellabel.place(x = 30, y = 142)
telentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = telephone, width = 20, bg = "white")
telentry.place(x = 130, y = 144)

adrlabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "address", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
adrlabel.place(x = 30, y = 182)
adrentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = address, width = 20, bg = "white")
adrentry.place(x = 130, y = 184)

ziplabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "zip", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
ziplabel.place(x = 30, y = 222)
zipentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = zipad, width = 20, bg = "white")
zipentry.place(x = 130, y = 224)

citylabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "city", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
citylabel.place(x = 30, y = 262)
cityentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = city, width = 20, bg = "white")
cityentry.place(x = 130, y = 264)

statelabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "state", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
statelabel.place(x = 30, y = 302)
stateentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = state, width = 20, bg = "white")
stateentry.place(x = 130, y = 304)

numberlabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "number", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
numberlabel.place(x = 320, y = 62)
numberentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = number, width = 20, bg = "white")
numberentry.place(x = 420, y = 64)

explabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "exp. date", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
explabel.place(x = 320, y = 102)
expentry1 = Entry(screen, textvariable = datem, width = 5, bg = "white")
expentry1.place(x = 420, y = 104)
expentry2 = Entry(screen, textvariable = datey, width = 8, bg = "white")
expentry2.place(x = 470, y = 104)

cvvlabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "cvv", bg = "white", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
cvvlabel.place(x = 320, y = 142)
cvventry = Entry(screen, textvariable = cvv, width = 5, bg = "white")
cvventry.place(x = 420, y = 144)

keywordlabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "keyword", bg = "orange", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
keywordlabel.place(x = 320, y = 222)
keywordentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = keyword, width = 20, bg = "orange")
keywordentry.place(x = 420, y = 224)

colorlabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "color", bg = "orange", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
colorlabel.place(x = 320, y = 262)
colorentry = Entry(screen, textvariable = color, width = 20, bg = "orange")
colorentry.place(x = 420, y = 264)

sizelabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "size", bg = "orange", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
sizelabel.place(x = 320, y = 300)
sizelist = ["S", "M", "L","XL"]
size.set(sizelist[0])
sizemenu = OptionMenu(screen, size, *sizelist)
sizemenu.configure(font = ("Courier", 10),bg = "orange")
sizemenu.place(x = 415, y = 302)

categorylabel = Label(screen, width = 10, text = "category", bg = "orange", fg = "black", font = ("Courier", 10), anchor = W)
categorylabel.place(x = 320, y = 182)
categorylist = ["jackets", "shirts", "tops_sweaters","sweatshirts", "pants", "shorts", "t-shirts", "hats", "bags", "accessories", "skate", "shoes"]
category.set(categorylist[0])
categorymenu = OptionMenu(screen, category, *categorylist)
categorymenu.configure(font = ("Courier", 9),bg = "orange")
categorymenu.place(x = 415, y = 184)

button1 = Button(screen, text="START", command=web)
button1.configure(font = ("Courier", 12), bg = "green", width = 10, height = 2)
button1.place(x=480,y=330)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can simplify the following xpath (not sure how UI affects implementation)

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts')
firstMatch = d.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Crewneck")]//parent::h1/following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "Red")]')
print(firstMatch.text)
```

Using variables:

```
keyWord = 'Crewneck'
colour = 'Red'
firstMatch = d.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "' + keyWord + '")]//parent::h1/following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "' + colour + '")]')
print(firstMatch.text)
```

Comment: I have tried this already and would want it to be variable by user. 'firstMatch = d.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Formula Crewneck")]//parent::h1/following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "Red")]')'  .For example  instead of Formula Crewneck I want to have something like format(keyword.get()) that will grab it from EntryBox and same with Red using format(color.get()). How do I put it together ?

Comment: So the content inside of the brackets is variable in search and is not just limited to what I have put in there as you showed.

Comment: See my version below

Comment: 'firstMatch = d.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "' + keyword + '")]//parent::h1/following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "' + colour + '")]')
NameError: name 'd' is not defined'

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: replace d with driver as you defined as driver in your code I assume

Comment: Changed it the way you said. Now it simply clicks the first item in the category when it opens the link 'firstMatch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "' + keyword +'")]//parent::h1/following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(), "' + color + '")]').click()' Doesn't take me down the right path. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Give me the keyword and colour and expected link to follow

Comment: Ok. So you have the code. For example I enter the category and the link follows to sweatshirts. That was easy to do. When I am in https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/#categories/Sweatshirts I want the program grab keyword : Formula and color : Natural that I have entered before and click on the picture that corresponds to those two variables. This should be the final link https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/#products/172110/22899 .But it shouldn’t matter since the user defines all category, keyword and color. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks. The code didn’t take me to the right path

Comment: Your links are not the same. My code is for the link you shared in the question.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just gave you a final destination link. First it goes to the /category link and then should choose the item according to variables. Sorry for confusion